# What report framework in java do you know?

Tags: java, report

I need to dinamicly create different report in Java on the serverside using data from database. What framework can I use for this aim?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically?  The content and data of the report or Ad-Hoc reporting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/index.php?q=project/jasperreports) is one of the most used java libraries for reporting.  It has a nice IDE called IReport and integrates into Netbeans nicely.  The documentation is okay and there are a few books and tutorials out there to help get you started

Answer (score 0):

[JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) and [Birt](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) are two good and free candidates.